# How to pick up the background color of a cell from one page and paste it into cells on other pages in Googl Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, formula

I have a Google Sheet with two pages.
On the first page, there is a table, and I can make changes to the "Directions" column by choosing options from the dropdown list. The data of the list are on the second page.

It works well with data. But also, I want to change the background color in the "Directions" cells on the first page depending on which numbers are chosen. How can I do that?

The link to the shhet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-O0D0KawVHIuRfguOCMrWbOTq7RNSAYpR8sfRRFbdzs/edit#gid=0

I tried some formulas but I didn't find an appropriate

Answer (score 0):

As one direction, how about setting the conditional formatting rules using Google Apps Script? When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please confirm the sheet names and ranges again, and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Table");
  const range1 = sheet1.getRange("C3:C" + sheet1.getLastRow());
  const values1 = range1.getValues();
  const colors1 = range1.getBackgrounds();
  const range2 = sheet2.getRange("C2:C" + sheet2.getLastRow());
  const rules = values1.map(([c], i) =>
    SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule().setRanges([range2]).whenNumberEqualTo(c).setBackground(colors1[i][0]).build()
  );
  sheet2.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

- **First, this sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this. Please test this script on your provided Spreadsheet.**
- When this script is run, the values and the background colors are retrieved from "C3:C" of "Data" sheet. And using the retrieved values and background colors, the conditional formatting rules are set to "C2:C" of "Table" sheet. By this, when the dropdown list of "C2:C" of "Table" sheet is changed, the background colors are also changed by the conditional formatting rules.
- When you change the values and the background colors of "C3:C" of "Data" sheet are changed, please run this script again. By this, the conditional formatting rules are updated.
- Of course, I think that this can be also manually set. But, I thought that when Google Apps Script is used, the operation might be simple.

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- As one of several approaches, I thought that the OnEdit trigger might be able to be also used. In this answer, as one of them, I proposed a direction for using conditional formatting rules.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder)
- [setConditionalFormatRules(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setconditionalformatrulesrules)

Comment: @ichark Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Thank you a lot!!!` and the current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. If my answer was not useful, I have to apologize. So, can I ask you about the detail of `Thank you a lot!!!`?